# SQL Right Excluding JOIN and WHERE issues

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, right-join

I am trying to create a view with a right excluding join:

[image]

However there is a colon that i also want to do a WHERE on. In this case its:

```
WHERE table.colon != 'x';
```

for that reason i have tried:

```
WHERE A.key IS NULL AND table.colon != 'x';
```

but when i run it, no data is shown when i run it.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advanced.

UPDATE, here is the query i am trying to run:

```
SELECT     dbo.DimServere.Servernavn, dbo.DimServere.Serverstatus, dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.IP_Adresse, dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Release_, dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Level_, 
                      dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Edition_, dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Build, dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Updates_Available, dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Supported_, 
                      dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Support_Status
FROM         dbo.DimServere RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer ON dbo.DimServere.TcpIpAddress = dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.IP_Adresse AND dbo.DimServere.Serverstatus <> 'Disposed/Retired'
WHERE     (dbo.DimServere.TcpIpAddress IS NULL)
```

Comment: Add a tag for the db type you are using. You can also consider using `MINUS` or `SUBTRACT` or `EXCEPT` depending on your flavour.

Comment: @Glenn I am using a SQL server 2008 R2 and using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: where is `table.colon` coming from?

Comment: @vkp from table a, i will update the post with the query

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition into the JOIN clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table2
        ON Table1.Field = Table2.Field AND
        Table2.OtherField != 'x'
WHERE Table2.Field IS NULL
```

Comment: hmm i have runned it and still no result

Comment: What do you mean by no result? No rows come back at all? Or unexpected results are returned?

Comment: No rows come back at all. Just blank. As you can see i have updated the post with the query. Incl what you told me to try.

Comment: That should only happen if for every tcp ip address in dbo.DimServere there is a matching tcp ip address in dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer  and none of them have a exactly equal to 'Disposed/Retired'. I notice there's a slash in the status, is that 2 different statuses or just one status?

Comment: There are a match. When i remove where != 'disposed/retired' it works. And its one status.

Comment: Why do you return fields in the SELECT clause from the dbo.DimServere table? If the query is working like you expect, those fields will always be null.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is correct. However, i guess there are `null` values in the `dbo.DimServere.Serverstatus` column. Because you are using an comparison operator, this condition always fails (comparison with `null` is unknown) and the `join` condition is not satisfied, (because you are `AND`ing it with another condition) and you don't get any results.

To overcome this, use `isnull(dbo.DimServere.Serverstatus, 'somevalue')` in the `join` condition.

```
SELECT dbo.DimServere.Servernavn, dbo.DimServere.Serverstatus,
dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.IP_Adresse, dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Release_,
dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Level_, dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Edition_, 
dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Build, dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Updates_Available,    
dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Supported_, dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.Support_Status
FROM dbo.DimServere RIGHT OUTER JOIN
dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer ON dbo.DimServere.TcpIpAddress = dbo.IderaPatchAnalyzer.IP_Adresse 
AND isnull(dbo.DimServere.Serverstatus, 'somevalue') <> 'Disposed/Retired' 
WHERE dbo.DimServere.TcpIpAddress IS NULL
```

Comment: Negative, i just ran SELECT * FROM [SIT-DVH].[dbo].[DimServere] WHERE Serverstatus IS NULL; and no rows showed up.

Comment: have you tried it without the `where` clause?just to check

Comment: Yes i have tried the query without AND dbo.DimServere.Serverstatus <> 'Disposed/Retired', then it works. But i need only to see data from the right side.

Comment: Sorry i meant, that i need to see only the right side without the Disposed/Retired values in the Serverstatus